# I want to create a list in R where I repeat the numbers in a sequence X amount of times whilst it counts chronologically?

Tags: r, list, sequence, repeat

I have a long table of let's say 198 variables. I would like to insert an ID column where R counts for me from 1-22 chronologically, repeating each count 9 times. (198/22=9)

In other words I want the sequence to go :
1 (9 times), 2 (9 times), 3(9 times) until it reaches 22 (9 times).
I have already tried different ways but have not been able to figure it out.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You can use `rep(1:22, each = 9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rep`

```
rep(1:22, each = 9)
```